# How to detect when the 'Current Page' option is selected (Print Dialog)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a print dialog which is used to print a document. The printing code works fine, however I would like to allow the user to be able to use the 'Current Page' option on the print dialog to print only the page which is being displayed in a print preview control in the background.

How do you catch or detect that the 'Current Page' option has been selected by the user?

Thanks.

Comment: I've found the answer myself but here's the code for future reference:

    If pDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.CurrentPage Then
       '...
    End If

:D

Answer (score 0):

From a browser, i don't think we can.

I tried this a while back, and couldn't fine a way to interact with the computers print functions.

In my case, we had different PDF's the user could download. Wasn't pretty.